# Connected component in locally finite graph is countable

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, cardinals

I have the following claim which I have been struggling to write a proof for:

> Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph such that $deg(v)<\infty$ for all $v\in V$. Then every connected component in the graph is countable.

So my reasoning was along the line of choosing a general vertex $v\in V$ and showing that its connected component $[v]_G$ is countable by writing it as $[v]_G=\sqcup_{n=0}^\infty D_n(v)$, where $D_n(v)$ is the set of vertices  in $G$ at distance $n$ from $v$. Since $D_n(v)$ is finite at all, $[v]_G$ is a countable union of finite sets and hence countable.

My issue is with writing why $D_n(v)$ is finite rigorously. I would like to use a straightforward argument of giving an upper bound which is countable, but since the degree is only finite and not bounded I think to say this one has to use an induction argument.

I would appreciate if any one has some direct, non inductive, argument to show that $D_n(v)$ is finite. If any one thinks there is an error in any of the above arguments, I would also be thankful if someone were to point them out.

Comment: I can't see a way of avoiding induction (or proof by contradiction). Why do you want to? The inductive proof is rather straightforward.

Comment: @DánielG. It lengthens the proof quite significantly, which I was hoping to avoid.

Comment: Why does induction lengthen the proof significantly? $D_n(v)$ is a finite union of finite sets, since it is the union of $\{D_1(v')\mid v'\in D_{n-1}(v)\}$. (Or at the very least $D_n$ is covered by that set, they are equal if there are no cycles in the graph.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Well, the induction argument I had in mind was longer and more convoluted. I was planning on writing the explicit size of each set while enumerating the vertices in each step.

Comment: That sounds awful. (And that's the difference in thinking between combinatorics and set theory: in combinatorics "finite" means that you computed an upper bound; in set theory finite is just "not infinite".)